# Can not read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I made a program that has 17 balls and then the user types in the number of balls he wants to see. After that, the program is supposed to generate random number balls on the screen of that specific number. E.g. if the user says he wants to see 5 balls he can just type 5 and 5 balls or different numbers will be displayed. But the problem is, the output is not correct and I am getting an error "Cannot read property 'id' of undefined". Here r my codes. I will mention in the codes the exact line where I am getting an error.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload=draw;
  function draw(){
    var canvas= document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
    var id;
    var x;
    var y;
    var r;
    var i;
    var balls=[{"id":1,"x":85,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":2,"x":180,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":3,"x":270,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":4,"x":360,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":5,"x":450,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":6,"x":535,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":7,"x":623,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":8,"x":710,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":9,"x":85,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":10,"x":180,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":11,"x":270,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":12,"x":360,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":13,"x":450,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":14,"x":535,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":15,"x":623,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":16,"x":710,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":17,"x":450,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":18,"x":535,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":19,"x":623,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":20,"x":710,"y":190,"r":40}];
    var texts=[];

    for(i=0;i<balls.length;i++){
      texts[i]=i;
    }

    var choose;
    choose=parseFloat(prompt("enter the number of balls u want to see"));
    for (var i=1; i<=choose; i++) {
      var x=Math.floor((Math.random() * choose) + 1);
      for (var k=1; k<=balls.length; k++) {
        var b=balls[k];
        if(b.id==x){                  /*here is the issue*/
          ctx.fillStyle="#800000";
          ctx.strokeStyle="#000000";
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.arc(b.x,b.y,b.r,0, 2 * Math.PI);
          ctx.stroke();
          ctx.fill();
          ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
          ctx.fillText(b.id, b.x, b.y);
        }
      }
    }
  }

</script>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800" style="border: 2px solid #000000"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: start your for loop at 0 and loop only over `k<balls.length`. VTC as "typo / not useful for future readers" because this is a really basic for loop error that you should have found in any introduction to programming paper.

Comment: Yea getting the result now thanks but the required number of circles aren't appearing :/ for example if i write 6 i get 4 or 5 and when i type 3 i get 2 or something. How do i fix that?

Comment: This is because you did the same error with the first loop : `for(i=0; i<choose; i++)`

Comment: i tried that too but it still isn't working :/

Comment: This is because you did the same error with the first loop : `i` should start at 0. `for(i=0; i <=choose; i++)` https://jsfiddle.net/2hnrtbgt/2/ (removed the randomness, btw you're doing it wrong but you should first start to understand how for loops do work)

Answer (score 0):

Two lines before the error, in your `for` loop :

```
var k=1; k<=balls.length; k++
```

Should be this instead :

```
var k=1; k<balls.length; k++
```

Otherwise, the last iteration is over the maximum index of the `balls` array, and you get `undefined` instead of a ball as you expect.

Comment: it still doesn't display all the required circles for example, when i write 4 i get 3 circles and sometimes when i write 6 i get 4 or 5 circles and something like this :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete re-write that works.  I fixed other issues like the `k < balls.length`, `parseInt` instead of `parseFloat` and breaking out of the loop once the correct ball to be displayed was found.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload=draw;
  function draw(){
    var canvas= document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
    var id;
    var x;
    var y;
    var r;
    var i;
    var balls=[{"id":1,"x":85,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":2,"x":180,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":3,"x":270,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":4,"x":360,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":5,"x":450,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":6,"x":535,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":7,"x":623,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":8,"x":710,"y":90,"r":40},{"id":9,"x":85,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":10,"x":180,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":11,"x":270,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":12,"x":360,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":13,"x":450,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":14,"x":535,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":15,"x":623,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":16,"x":710,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":17,"x":450,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":18,"x":535,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":19,"x":623,"y":190,"r":40},{"id":20,"x":710,"y":190,"r":40}];

    var choose;
    choose=parseInt(prompt("enter the number of balls u want to see"));

    var randomlySelectedBalls = [];
    var i = 0;
    while (i < choose){
      var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * (balls.length + 1)));
      if( randomlySelectedBalls.indexOf(x) === -1) {
        randomlySelectedBalls.push(x);
        for (var k=0; k<balls.length; k++) {
          var b=balls[k];
          if(b.id==x){                  /*here is the issue*/
            ctx.fillStyle="#800000";
            ctx.strokeStyle="#000000";
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.arc(b.x,b.y,b.r,0, 2 * Math.PI);
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
            ctx.fillText(b.id, b.x, b.y);
            break;
          }
        }
        i++;
      }
    }
  }

</script>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="800" style="border: 2px solid #000000"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks. However, the output doesn't show the required circles. if i type 3 i get 1 or 2 and if i type 6 i get 5 or 4 or something. What do i do? :/

Comment: You are not picking unique random numbers each time.  You could pick the number 3 two times, and only one number 3 ball will show up.